# Is there an easy way to get a ParentRecord plus List<ChildRecord> in jooq?

Tags: jooq

Looking at the [Sakila database](https://github.com/jOOQ/sakila) I wonder how could I write a query that gets me a Country plus all Cities in the country.

I imagine it returning Result<Record2<CountryRecord,List>.  Does that make sense?  I might want a country plus all cities attached to it in one jooq query?  I assume it might use the multiset under the covers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution without `MULTISET`

In your particular case, it doesn't seem you need to use `MULTISET`, you can just use a classic join based solution, e.g.

```java
Map<CountryRecord, Result<CityRecord>> map = ctx
    .select()
    .from(CITY)
    .join(COUNTRY).on(CITY.COUNTRY_ID.eq(COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID))
    .fetchGroups(COUNTRY, CITY);
```

It's creating a `Map<CountryRecord, Result<CityRecord>>`, which is almost the same as what you requested.

#### jOOQ 3.17 solution using `MULTISET`

In jOOQ 3.17, [#4727](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4727) was implemented allowing to use any `Table<R>` reference as a `SelectField<R>` to project table expressions just like in PostgreSQL, producing the generated nominal record types instead of the strucural `Record[N]` types. You can then write:

```java
Result<Record2<CountryRecord, Result<CityRecord>>> result = ctx
    .select(

        // You can project any table expression here
        COUNTRY,
        multiset(
            selectFrom(CITY)
                .where(CITY.COUNTRY_ID.eq(CITY.COUNTRY_ID))
        ))
    .from(COUNTRY)
    .fetch();
```

This is the exact type you wanted (`Result` extends `List`, so I'm assuming this is fine). Different types can be created by using different kinds of [ad-hoc conversion](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/)

See also:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/tables-as-selectfield/

#### jOOQ 3.16 solution using `MULTISET`

Without the above means to project a generated record, you can do this to project them manually:

```java
Result<Record2<CountryRecord, Result<CityRecord>>> result = ctx
    .select(

        // Manually nest all columns of a table in a nested record
        row(COUNTRY.fields()).convertFrom(r -> r.into(COUNTRY)),
        multiset(
            selectFrom(CITY)
                .where(CITY.COUNTRY_ID.eq(CITY.COUNTRY_ID))
        ))
    .from(COUNTRY)
    .fetch();
```

This obviously still works in jOOQ 3.17 as well